# Error while loading the .swc file when migrated from IE7 to IE8

Tags: actionscript-3

I was trying to load a swc file on on demand basis and it was working fine untill i upgraded my IE from IE7 to IE8 . Iam getting the following error .Can somebody please put some insight in as to why Iam getting the following error.

VerifyError: Error #1014: Class spark.components::Application could not be found.

```
at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Direcion gigen

Answer (score 0):

the swc file gets compiled and becomes part of the final swf. I can't see any reason why the resulting swf would act any different in IE7 vs IE8.

try using swf files on demand.

Comment: Is there any thing related to FlashPlayer10 upgrade . How do i force Flashbuilder to run on a particular Flashplayer ,because I see that there are 2 players like 10 and 10.1